# Compare two NSStrings

Tags: cocoa-touch, nsstring, string-comparison

In my app there is a mechanism that requires that at a certain point two `NSString`s will be the same to do something; for some reason when I compare the two, even when they are the same, it still doesn't recognize that. The code is something like this:

```
NSString * aString = [self someMethodThatGetsAString];

NSString * bString;

BOOL areStringsTheSame = NO;

while (areStringsTheSame != YES) {

       bString = [self someMethodThatTakesNSStringsFromAnArrey];
       if (bString == aString) {
             areStringsTheSame = YES;
       { }
```

I even inserted an `NSLog()` and made sure that at a certain point they were the same (and as far as I know this is what `==` stands for...), but still it didn't get into the `if` to change the `BOOL` value.

Is there another way to do this comparison? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You can use the method [isEqualToString:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html):

```
if ([bString isEqualToString:aString])
```

`==` compares the references (addresses of) the strings, and not the value of the strings.

Comment: True. And dig into the principles of OOP (two objects with the same properties are not necessarily the same objects). Otherwise, you're gonna encounter this problem every day of your developer life :-)

Comment: Apparently `==` works just as well to compare strings case-sensitively, because of the way Objective-C uses string variables.  For example, declare a string A and string B, and do `==` and you'll find they are both stored in the same address.

Answer (score 5):

This approach worked for me:

```
if ([firstString compare:secondString] == NSOrderedSame) {
    //Do something when they are the same
} else {
    //Do something when they are different
}
```

Comment: I found today, this returns `NSOrderedSame` if one is `nil` and one isn't

Answer (score 4):

Recently I was shocked by the fact that two NSStrings that resemble each other on NSLog may be different. It is because sometimes NSString can contain a zero width space character. Be aware of that and consider:

```
#define ZERO_WIDTH_SPACE_STRING @"\u200B"
```

To conquer this you should clean your string from zero width white space characters before comparing:

```
NSMutableString *eMailToAdd = [NSMutableString string];

NSMutableCharacterSet *charSet = [[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet] mutableCopy];
    //[charSet formUnionWithCharacterSet:[NSCharacterSet punctuationCharacterSet]];

    NSString *rawStr = [[tokenField textField] text];
    for (int i = 0; i < [rawStr length]; i++)
    {
        if (![charSet characterIsMember:[rawStr characterAtIndex:i]])
        {
            [eMailToAdd appendFormat:@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", [rawStr characterAtIndex:i]]];
        }
    }
```